# randomly replace item in list

Tags: python, list, replace

I have two lists `A =[2,3,4,5,33,42,21]` and `B = [1,11,35,48,19]` I want to randomly delete two items of list `B` and replace with two random items from list `A` for 200 iteration. I used this code but only one item of `B` replace with `A`. how can I do that?

```
import random

A = [2,3,4,5,33,42,21]
B = [1,11,35,48,19]

x = random.randrange(0,5)
i = A[x]
A[x] = B[x]
B[x] = i
print(A)
print(B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

```
import random

list_a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 33, 42, 21]
list_b = [1, 11, 35, 48, 19]

a_index1, a_index2 = random.sample(range(len(list_a)), k=2)
b_index1, b_index2 = random.sample(range(len(list_b)), k=2)
list_a[a_index1], list_b[b_index1] = list_b[b_index1], list_a[a_index1]
list_a[a_index2], list_b[b_index2] = list_b[b_index2], list_a[a_index2]
```

The only thing needed to be added here is to put it in a loop and loop 200 times.

`random.sample` chooses `k` unique choices from an iterable so there won't be a case where it chooses the same integer twice in an iteration.

If you attempt to use the same index for both `list_a` and `list_b` you will never replace the final 2 elements in `list_a` since `list_b` is shorter and does not have an equivalent index.

Edit:

Regarding the question to expand this:

Currently, the indexes are unpacked into 2 variables. When you change to `k=5`, you are attempting to unpack a `list` of 5 values into 2 variables.

The proper solution is to make it dynamic.

```
import random

def swap(list_a, list_b, indexes_to_swap=2):
    a_indexes = random.sample(range(len(list_a)), k=indexes_to_swap)
    b_indexes = random.sample(range(len(list_b)), k=indexes_to_swap)
    for a_index, b_index in zip(a_indexes, b_indexes):
        list_a[a_index], list_b[b_index] = list_b[b_index], list_a[a_index]

list_a = [3,4,15,18,21,35,36,45,47]
list_b = [0,1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,19,20,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,46,48]
swap(list_a, list_b, 5)
```

If you wish to do it 200 times:

```
for _ in range(200):
    swap(list_a, list_b, 5)
```

Comment: I only need `list_b`. so I want to randomly remove 2 items of `list_b` and put 2 items Instead of them from `list_a`.@Axe319

Comment: So you want to remove them from `list_a`? Doesn't that mean after 4 iterations `list_a` will be depleted?

Comment: one question,when I changed `list_a =  [3,4,15,18,21,35,36,45,47] ` and `list_b = [0,1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,19,20,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,46,48]` and I want to replace 5 members , but when I changed  `k=5` the error was `too many values to unpack`. How can I do it?

Comment: @mohammadhassanmoayyedian I edited and added an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.@Axe319

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```
import random

A = [2,3,4,5,33,42,21]
B = [1,11,35,48,19]


for _ in range(400):
    x = random.randrange(0,5)
    A[x], B[x] = B[x], A[x]
print(A)
print(B)
```

You want to loop 400 times since you want to change 2 items for each iteration and you want to iterate for 200 times. You could also do this:

```
import random

A = [2,3,4,5,33,42,21]
B = [1,11,35,48,19]


for _ in range(200):
    x = random.randrange(0,5)
    y = random.randrange(0,5)
    while y == x:
        y = random.randrange(0,5)
    A[x], B[x] = B[x], A[x]
    A[y], B[y] = B[y], A[y]
print(A)
print(B)
```

This has the "benefit" that the 2 replacements are never the same(which you might have asked?)

Comment: Curiosity: technically this might never ends :)

Comment: Yeah that's true :(

Comment: @RiccardoBucco. thanks. one question!I tested your code for 10 iterations and I realized that Only one member of `B` has changed. this is result based on your code `[1, 11, 35, 5, 19]` and only `5` has changed.